# file system, native process utility libraries for Adobe AIR/flex applications

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am looking for utility/helper classes for Adobe AIR/actionscript 3.0 file system and native process utilization. Could someone point me to opensource library projects specific to Adobe AIR..

Thx

Comment: What features exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Basic wrappers e.g. create a directory, create a file, call a process, delete directory etc

Answer (score 0):

You could try the classes in this project https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib. The package is com.adobe.air.filesystem. Also regarding native process this devnet article can be helpful http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has a list of some of the Native Extensions the community has developed at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html